# Can't load custom PHP module

Tags: php, c

It compiles into a DLL w/o problems.  But then it's not being recognized as loaded when I use the `extension_loaded` function in PHP or look it up in the `phpinfo` list.  I put the DLL into the extensions folder then add it's entry into php.ini.  I think the problem may be in the code.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

```
ZEND_FUNCTION(MyFunction) 
{

    char var1 = NULL;
    char var2 = NULL;
    char var3 = NULL;
    char var4 = NULL;
    char var5 = NULL;
    char var6 = NULL;
    int var7;
    double *var8;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ssssssla", &var1, &var2,
                                &var3, &var4, &var5, &var6, &var7, &var8) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }

    Cfunction(&var1,&var2,&var3,&var4,&var5, &var6, var7, var8);

    RETURN_TRUE;
}

zend_function_entry MyExtension_functions[] = {
    ZEND_FE(MyFunction, NULL)
    {NULL,NULL,NULL}
};


PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(MyExtension) {
    return SUCCESS;
}

PHP_MSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(MyExtension) {
    return SUCCESS;
}

PHP_MINFO_FUNCTION(MyExtension) {
    php_info_print_table_start();
    php_info_print_table_header(2, "MyExtension v1.0", "");
    php_info_print_table_row(2, "PHP Extension", "enabled");
    php_info_print_table_end();
} 




zend_module_entry MyExtension_module_entry = {
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
#endif
    "MyExtension",
     MyExtension_functions,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    PHP_MINFO(MyExtension),
    "1.0",
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

    ZEND_GET_MODULE(MyExtension)
```

Comment: Did you restart the web server after installing the extension and adding it to php.ini? What error message are you getting?

Comment: Yes I restarted the web server.  An error message from the server or php?

Comment: sure you're modifying the right .ini file? check `phpinfo()`'s output to see which one you should be changing.

Comment: Yes, I'm modifying the right .ini file.  I checked `phpinfo()` to be sure.

Comment: enable `show_startup_errors` in php.ini. Otherwise messages because of faulty extensions will get silenced

Comment: @hek2mgl like this `display_startup_errors = On` ?  Then I can view any errors in the web server log?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to view extension loading errors is to run `php.exe` from command line.  This showed me error messages of

```
Warning: PHP Startup: MyExtension: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

So I found the `#define ZEND_MODULE_API_NO` in zend_modules.h and changed it from 20121212 to 20090626.

Then it complained with:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: MyExtension: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS,VC10
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS,VC9
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

So I found `#define PHP_COMPILER_ID` in config.w32.h and changed it from "VC10" to "VC9".

After this it loaded the module.  I was able to call my function but it came back with a tradition 500 error.  I suspect this has something to do with the VC9/VC10 incompatibility.

The moral of the story is that I tried to use extension compiled with VC10 when the PHP I was using was compiled with VC9.  This leads to all sorts of errors.  The appropriate thing to do is then compile PHP src with VC10.